# Change color of text inputted

Tags: javascript, html

I have a **text box** through which I input text and display it in a **paragraph** below after I click a **button.** However I want the multiples of 3 to displayed a **different color** e.g blue.

If I enter **I am Batman**. Then I want m,t,n and so on to be colored blue. 
How do I achieve this? 
Any help is appreciated.

Here is the code that I tried:

```js
function change() {
  myOutput = document.getElementById('output');
  textbox = document.getElementById('text').value;
  myOutput.innerHTML = "You entered: " + textbox;
  var arr = textbox.split('');
  console.log(arr);
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 3) {
    console.log(i);
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="text" />
<button onclick="change()">Change</button>
<p id="output"></p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function change() {
  myOutput = document.getElementById('output');
  textbox = document.getElementById('text').value;
  
  var arr = textbox.split('');
  var newText = '';
  console.log(arr);
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if(i%3==2){
      newText += "<strong style='color:blue'>"+arr[i]+"</strong>";
    }else{
      newText += arr[i];
    }
  }
  myOutput.innerHTML = "You entered: " + newText;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="text" />
<button onclick="change()">Change</button>
<p id="output"></p>
```

Comment: @SLASH It's my pleasure :)

Comment: @SLASH Normally,when I get multiple of 3, I use `if(i%3==0)`. but, this case is different. `var i` started from `0`. So, I need to change `if(i%3==0)`. Do you know about `%` operator?

Comment: Yea it gives the remainder of a division.